Return the year of the first mention of a string in Google using RSelenium
I have a list of strings (slightly over a thousand), and I would like to find out the year when each string was mentioned in the web for the first time and save the link of the webpage where this "oldest" mention was found (and store both in a dataframe). When I had to do this with a much smaller sample, I just did it manually by playing with custom time ranges for my Google searches (i.e. reducing the range until no pages were found). Now I'm trying to use web scraping which I've never used before, and together with YouTube and ChatGPT I managed to come up with the following code:
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(netstat)
library(stringi)

# Creating a random dataframe for reproduction

first_names <- c("John", "Emily", "Michael", "Sarah", "David", "Jessica", "Daniel", "Emma", "James", "Olivia",
                 "Robert", "Sophia", "William", "Isabella", "Richard", "Mia", "Joseph", "Ava", "Charles", "Charlotte")

surnames <- c("Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Brown", "Jones", "Garcia", "Miller", "Davis", "Martinez", "Hernandez",
              "Lopez", "Gonzalez", "Wilson", "Anderson", "Thomas", "Taylor", "Moore", "Jackson", "Martin", "Lee")

# Function to generate a random name
generate_random_name <- function() {
  first_name <- sample(first_names, 1)
  surname <- sample(surnames, 1)
  return(paste(first_name, surname))
}

# Generate a vector of 1,000 random names
random_names <- replicate(1000, generate_random_name())
projects <- data.frame(Name = random_names, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Start the RSelenium server
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = free_port(), verbose = FALSE)
remDr <- rD$client

# Function to find the earliest year of mention
find_earliest_mention <- function(project_name) {
  # Navigate to Google and perform a search
  search_url <- paste0("https://www.google.com/search?q=", URLencode(project_name, reserved = TRUE))
  remDr$navigate(search_url)
  
  # Wait for the page to load
  Sys.sleep(5) # Increase sleep time to ensure page is fully loaded
  
  # Extract the page source
  page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
  
  # Debugging: Save the page source to a file to inspect it later
  write(page_source, file = paste0("debug_", gsub(" ", "_", project_name), ".html"))
  
  # Parse the HTML content
  page <- read_html(page_source)
  
  # Extract the snippets containing dates
  snippets <- page %>%
    html_nodes(".BNeawe.s3v9rd.AP7Wnd") %>%
    html_text()
  
  # Extract all result links
  links <- page %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>%
    html_attr("href")
  
  # Filter to include only links that are actual result links (starting with "/url?q=")
  links <- links[grepl("^/url\\?q=", links)]
  
  # Clean up the links to be complete URLs
  links <- sub("^/url\\?q=", "", links)
  links <- sapply(links, function(link) strsplit(link, "&")[[1]][1])
  
  # Find all years in the snippets
  years <- str_extract(snippets, "\\b\\d{4}\\b")
  years <- as.numeric(years[!is.na(years)])
  
  # Debugging: Print out snippets, links, and years
  print(list(snippets = snippets, links = links, years = years))
  
  # Return the earliest year found and the corresponding link
  if (length(years) > 0) {
    earliest_year <- min(years)
    link_index <- which.min(years)
    earliest_link <- links[link_index]
    return(list(year = earliest_year, link = earliest_link))
  } else {
    return(list(year = NA, link = NA))
  }
}

# Loop through each project and find the earliest mention and link
results <- data.frame(
  Project = projects$ProjectName,
  EarliestYear = NA,
  Link = NA,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

for (i in 1:nrow(projects)) {
  result <- find_earliest_mention(projects$ProjectName[i])
  results$EarliestYear[i] <- result$year
  results$Link[i] <- result$link
}

# Close the RSelenium session
remDr$close()
rD$server$stop()

The code seems to run smoothly albeit for a long period of time given the number of strings. In the end, however, the resulting dataframe returns the initial strings with EarliestYear and Link columns filled with NA's.
My biggest question is whether what I'm aiming for is actually doable, as I understand I could have been blindfolded by ChatGPT. I would also appreciate more specific advice related to the code, or any sources that could help me achieve my goal.
